# What can be said about $ \hat{\otimes}_R:f\otimes g\mapsto f\otimes_R g$?

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products

**Edit:** I know the question is very vague; this is partly due to the fact that I stumbled upon this map rather accidentaly and that I just wondered what can be said about this. So if you have some thoughts about this, please share them :)

Let $R$ be a unital ring, possibly non-commutative. Let $M$ be a right $R$-module and $N$ be a left $R$-module. Then by the basic properties of the tensor product, we know that
$$
-\otimes_R-:\operatorname{End}_R(M,M)\times\operatorname{End}_R(N,N)\to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M\otimes_R N,M\otimes_R N)\\
(f,g)\mapsto f\otimes_R g 
$$
is additive in both arguments, and multiplicative in the sense that $(f\circ f')\otimes_R (g\circ g')=(f\otimes_R g)\circ(f'\otimes_R g')$. By the universal property of the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras, i.e. rings, this induces a ring homomorphism
$$
\hat{\otimes}_R:\operatorname{End}_R(M,M)\otimes_{\mathbb{z}}\operatorname{End}_R(N,N)\to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(M\otimes_R N,M\otimes_R N)\\
f\otimes g\mapsto f\otimes_R g.
$$
Can anything interesting be said about this ring homomorphism? E.g. is it injective? Or surjective? Or even bijective? And if not, what if we place stronger conditions on $R$?
Thanks for sharing any information that comes to your mind.

Comment: For vector spaces over a field $\Bbbk$, $\mathsf{End}_\Bbbk(U) \otimes_\Bbbk \mathsf{End}_\Bbbk(V) \to \mathsf{End}_\Bbbk(U \otimes_\Bbbk V)$ is injective. If either U or V is finite-dimensional, it is also surjective. In general no: the twist map $$\tau:\Bbbk[X] \otimes_\Bbbk \Bbbk[X] \to \Bbbk[X] \otimes_\Bbbk \Bbbk[X], X^i \otimes_\Bbbk X^j \mapsto X^j \otimes_\Bbbk X^i$$ is not in the image, for instance

Comment: For non-fields it can also be non-injective, e.g. over $\mathbb Z$ you can look at $M=\mathbb{Q/Z},  N=\mathbb Q$ for instance